# Calculation Limit Of Some Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

> Natural number $n$ and $\begin{cases} a_{1}=\cos 1 \\ a_{n}=\max(a_{n-1}, \cos n)\end{cases}$
>   Find the value of $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our sequence is non-decreasing, and bounded above. So it has a limit.

To see that the limit is $1$, use the fact that the set of numbers of the form $\cos n$ is **dense** in the interval $[-1,1]$.

For any positive integer $n$, we can find a unique integer $q_n$, and a number $r_n$ such that $0\le r_n\lt 2\pi$, such that $n=2\pi q_n+r_n$.  We want to show that the $r_n$ are dense in the interval $[0,2\pi)$.

Equivalently, we want to show that the numbers $\frac{r_n}{2\pi}$ are dense in the interval $[0,1)$. Since $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ is irrational, this follows from the standard fact that if $\tau$ is irrational, then the set of fractional parts of the numbers $n\tau$ is dense in $[0,1)$.

**Remark:** For a more intuitive but not fully persuasive argument, think of the unit circle with centre the origin. Let $P_0=(1,0)$. For any $n$, the point $P_{n+1}$ is obtained by rotating $P_n$ about the origin through a $1$ radian angle. Then it seems reasonable that the set of points of the shape $P_n$ is dense in the unit circle.  Thus the coordinates of $P_n$, which are $\cos n$ and $\sin n$, are each dense in the interval $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how the dense property of $\cos n$ and the limit (the supreme) are related, yet.

Comment: Could you explain the detail, more?

Comment: @Headhunter: Which part should be amplified on? The fact that fractional parts of $n\tau$ are dense in $[0,1)$ is quite standard, it is a Pigeonhole Principle argument, has appeared several times on MSE. I think that the fact $\cos n$, $\sin n$ are dense has also been proved on MSE more than once.

Comment: Ah, I got it now. So sorry for my sluggish understanding. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a_n=max\{a_{n-1}, \cos n\} \geq a_{n-1}$ and $a_n \leq \cos x \leq 1$, by monotone sequence theorem, the limit equals $\sup a_n=1$.

Comment: Thanks, but we can't tell that the supreme is 1.    
What is $a_{n}\leq \cos x$? I can't understand.

Comment: I got the sequence is increasing, but can't be certain about the supreme.